# mailx execution as non-root failing

Tags: mailx

I am running Oracle Linux 7 for the purpose of hosting an Oracle database.

As part of this process I run a script that mails a log file at the end on a daily basis.

Crux of my issue is that my script executes the mailx command as root with no issue.  When I run as the normal operation user "oracle", it fails with this error:

```
temporary mail file: No such file or directory
```

The failing command is:

```
cat $ORACLE_BASE/admin/DBSID/dpdump/EXPORT.log | mailx -r "FROMADD@domain.com" -s "subject" -S smtp="10.10.10.10:25" TOADDR@domain.com
```

I have already verified that the oracle user is in the mail group and have checked that the /TMP directory is of standard permission values.  I have also checked the permissions of the spool directory and its subfiles.

Comment: Please edit and add to your question, the value of the TMPDIR environment variable at the time `mailx` is invoked.  If it is non-empty, what is the output of `ls -ld $TMPDIR`?

Comment: Well now I feel about 4 inches tall.  Total rookie mistake.  the export command in the setEnv.sh script reads export TMP=/Tmp     That obviously won't work.  Removed the capital and it functions as planned.  Sorry to waste your time on something so simple

Comment: I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Jim L. comment on my question.  It drove me to the answer.  I had a bad export command that referenced /Tmp.  Altering this to what it should have been (/tmp) fixed the issue.  Lord save me from dumb typos.